# Jquery mobile and Facebook Login

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using the facebook JS SDK for a facebook login with Jquery mobile. On the initial page load, everything works fine - I see the button, I can get the login status, etc. When I link (via ajax) to another page, the button doesn't load and nothing works. It seems like the sdk is not loading and window.fbAsyncInit doesn't fire.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the way everything loads with jquery mobile pages, but I've tried everything. Placing the fb-root in various places, the init script in the header, the body and within the page, but I'm getting the same result.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with a mobile app I'm working on.  I haven't determined the exact problem, but it has to do with some loading events that can't occur over ajax.  The easiest way to fix the problem was to force my login page to not be loaded through ajax.  Use the *data-ajax* attribute.

```
 <a href="/login.htm" data-ajax="false">Login</a>
```

Ideally though, the login page loading event will be able to determine the method used.  Something like this maybe:

```
 $(document).on('pageinit','#login_page', function(){
      // if (page-load-event happened through ajax)
      location.reload(true);
 });
```

Essentially it's just refreshing the page.  Using true as the function argument will ensure it's not using anything cached, and pulling from the server again.